# A conjecture associated with n-gon cut curve of degree m

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, conjectures

This conjecture is a generalization of [A theorem for cubic-A generalization of Carnot theorem, in MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1440544/a-theorem-for-cubic-a-generalization-of-carnot-theorem).  I'm an electrical engineer, I am not a mathematician. I don't know how to prove this result.

Let $A_1A_2....A_n$ be a n-gons, Let $m$ points $B_{ij}$  lie on $A_iA_{i+1}$ for j=1, 2,...., m. Then $m.n$ points  $B_{ij}$ for $i=1, 2, 3,...., n$ and $j=1, 2,...., m$ lie on a curve of degree $m$ if only if:

$$\prod_{i=1}^n \prod_{j=1}^m \frac{\overline{B_{ij}A_i}}{\overline{B_{ij}A_{i+1}}}=1$$

Note that: $A_{m+1}=A_1$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you meant to type "curve of degree m". Let's prove the "only if" direction first. If you can prove it for triangles then you can triangulate your $n$-gon and multiply together the expressions for each triangle. So let's assume $n=3$.

Now, pick coordinates $(t_0,t_1,t_2)$ on $\mathbb P^2$ so that the lines $t_i=0$ correspond to the three lines of your triangle, and let $at_0+bt_1+bt_2$ be a generic line that doesn't pass through any of your points. Consider the three functions $$f_i=\frac{t_i}{at_0+bt_1+ct_2}$$
on your degree $m$ curve. [Weil reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_reciprocity_law) then tells you that $\prod_{P} (f_i,f_j)_P=1$ so you can write $$\prod_P (f_0,f_1)_P(f_1,f_2)_P(f_2,f_0)_P=1$$
and by the definition of the Weil symbol this ends up being exactly the product $\prod_{i=1}^n \prod_{j=1}^m \frac{\overline{B_{ij}A_i}}{\overline{B_{ij}A_{i+1}}}$ in your statement. I learned this proof [here](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/report_series/tcdmath/tcdm1303.pdf). Note that the result is true even if you let points coincide and count them with multiplicities.

To got the other way, omit one of the points and pick a degree $m$ curve through the remaining $3m-1$, by the calculation above the remaining point will be uniquely determined.

Comment: Yes, I meant to type "curve of degree m". Thank to You very much.

Comment: But in other direction, may we suppose that $n=3$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov, good point, I forgot to say anything about that. The statement in the other direction for $n\geq 4$ is false already for $m=1$.

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi Dear Professor Gjergji Zaimi, is the result new?